# Are the points on a line remain invariant to a linear mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Consider $x,y,z$ three points in a 2-D space, and they are placed on a straight line. So consider $\vec v_{xy}$ a vector from $x$ to $y$, and $\vec v_{xz}$ a vector from $x$ to $z$. So the angle between two vectors is zero ($\theta=0$) and also $\left | \vec v_{xy} \right | \lt \left | \vec v_{xz} \right |$

Is there any possible linear transformation in that space to increase the $\theta$ or to make $\left | \vec v_{xy} \right | \gt \left | \vec v_{xz} \right |$?

Comment: you have $y-x = \alpha (z-x)$ with $\alpha>1$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nonsingular affine transformations, of which linear transformations are a subset, map straight lines to straight lines and preserve the ratios of lengths of segments of the same line. Thus, if $|\vec v_{xy}|<|\vec v_{xz}|$ with the three points colinear, there’s no nonsingular affine transformation that can reverse this relationship. Similarly, the two vectors are colinear, so they must remain so under an affine transformation.

A singular transformation could collapse the line to a single point, making the both vector lengths zero and thus equal, but that’s not very interesting.